# Set the right-arrow icon of a specific QMenu in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets, qmenu

I am trying to change the icon of a QMenu's right arrow. The following QSS rule works

```
QMenu::right-arrow {
    image: url(icons:icon_name.svg);
}
```

However, it changes the right arrows of all QMenus. I want to select only QMenus that have some property/name. I tried the following things:

```
/* shouldHide is a boolean property set to true */
QMenu[shouldHide="true"]::right-arrow {
    image: url(icons:icon_name.svg);
}
```

```
QMenu::right-arrow[shouldHide="true"] {
    image: url(icons:icon_name.svg);
}
```

I also tried wrapping the QMenu in a hidden QWidget and setting the stylesheet on the parent

```
container->setStyleSheet("QMenu::right-arrow: {image: url(icons:icon_name.svg); }");
```

I also attempted to set the style sheet on the menu itself in the following ways:

```
menu->setStyleSheet("QMenu::right-arrow: {image: url(icons:icon_name.svg); }");
```

```
menu->setStyleSheet("*::right-arrow: {image: url(icons:icon_name.svg); }");
```

... and none of them work.

Comment: `QMenu#menu_object_name::right-arrow` Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, I did. It does not work.

Comment: in `qss` there is priority between styles, which means that you shouldn't add style for general QMenu First and then add `QMenu#menu_object_name::right-arrow` the first style and style that are upper has first priority so put your .qss file to question .

Answer (score -1):

This style will be applied for all `QMenu` Objects:

```css
QMenu::right-arrow 
{
        image: url(icons:icon_name.svg);
}
```

If you want only to apply to a specific object, you could use the object name of the object:

#### Only Object Name:

```css
#my_object_name::right-arrow 
{
        image: url(icons:icon_name.svg);
}
```

#### Object Name Of A Specefic Type

```css
QMenu#my_object_name::right-arrow 
{
        image: url(icons:icon_name.svg);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I tried it as well.